# IE opens ads automatically

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, windows-explorer

I have a problem. I use firefox for browsing, never open IE. But while working every now and then IE window opens with various ads even when i did not open it myself. This way a lot of instances of IE are opened making my system slow.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If IE started to open by it self I would be scared of malware or virus.

My suggestion is that you do scan for virus or malware of your computer, then do a windows update.

See [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) for more information.